# InDesign: master page item can't be removed after overriding it

Tags: color, master-page, adobe-indesign

I seem to have a strange problem. In InDesign, in the master page (right side / odd numbered pages) I have a simple graphic, but when I delete it using <kbd>ctrl+shift+click Delete</kbd>, another one is automatically generated. If I do the same on the left side, it's all fine.

For now I have just turned the colour to page colour (white).
Anyone know if there is a solution to this or is it just a glitch? All my other files are fine.

Comment: Very odd, but what happens if you just hit delete...:-S? And are you sure you do not have lots and lots of the same image on top of each other? Or the image locked to the page?

Answer (score 2):

> **When InDesign is behaving erratically,** deleting preferences (also
>   referred to as “trashing preferences” or “removing preferences”) often
>   [solves the problem.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/indesign/cs/using/WSa285fff53dea4f8617383751001ea8cb3f-6d21a.html)
>
> It’s a good idea to make a backup copy of the preference files called
>   InDesign Defaults and InDesign SavedData. Instead of removing your
>   preferences, you can copy these backup files over the problematic
>   corrupt preference files and not lose any customizations.

- **Do one of the following:**

> **(Windows)** Start InDesign, and then press
>   Shift+Ctrl+Alt. Click Yes when asked if you want to delete preference
>   files.
>   **(Mac OS)** While pressing Shift+Option+Command+Control, start
>   InDesign. Click Yes when asked if you want to delete preference files.

Answer (score 1):

If your master page item is touching the center/gutter line, then it will think that this item is for the left page as well, and so, it will keep the item, even when you <kbd>Shift</kbd>+`Click` to unlock it from the master items.

Solution: Just leave a very slight amount of space (1/32") from the center/gutter line.

Comment: The solution above: "Just leave a very slight amount of space (1/32") from the center/gutter line." worked for me.